# Searchview shows rectangle after clicking on text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-toolbar, searchview

I've got a simple toolbar:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarDriver"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:defaultQueryHint="@string/search_drivers"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            app:searchIcon="@null"
            />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>



</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: normal]

but when I click on the text, a random rectange appears:

[image: not normal]

How can I disable the rectange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme seems to be the issue... Try this:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/abLayoutDriver"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/BrightYellowCrayola">
```

Rather using android:theme which will overwrite the setting for the ENTIRE layout, put the theme content within the AppBarLayout.